# Windows System Recovery: Is it needed?

Tags: windows, system-recovery

I just recently deactivated system recovery on Vista, which saved me a huge amount of space. But I wonder is it necessary to have it activated? I can't remember that I any time had any use of system recovery anyway. And since it is Microsoft it probably would do a sloppy job anyway or?

This question is for Windows XP, Vista, and 7. Do you have it activated?
You can leave a comment if you have any opinion about the system recovery

Comment: no definitive answer unfortunately

Comment: @John T - I just want to hear some opintions, so if it is an answer or not does not matter.

Comment: @starcom no offense, I'm just trying to point out that this isn't a typical discussion forum. If you want opinions I'd mark your question as "Community Wiki" with the checkbox in edit mode. If you'd like it to remain a question format I'd just remove the opinionated portion else others will close the question on you.

Comment: @John T - Hmm, I don't have the option to mark this question as "Community Wiki". I'll just edit my question.

Comment: Typically, as computers go, when you don't have it is when you'll suddenly need it.  So by the karmic ways of the universe, having deactivated system recovery, your system will crash within two months and be unrecoverable without the system restore and you will have to reinstall everything from scratch.

Comment: (@John, CW [is no longer available](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192).)

Answer (score 2):

Back in the day when I used to use Windows, System Recovery came in handy to solve problems that had me absolutely stumped.

My suggestion is to try to keep this enabled.  It's better to have it and not need it than to need it and not have it.